# Labels in a diagonal resistor in circurtikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am drawing a simple diagram on circuitikz with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.25]
\ctikzset{label/align=smart,bipoles/length=1.5cm}
\draw (0,0) to[R,l_=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (4,0);
\draw (4,0) to[R,l^=\mbox{$R_2=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (2,3);
\draw (2,3) to[R,l_=\mbox{$R_3=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that `l_=` and `l^=` does not work with diagonal elements or am I missing something? How can I put  $R_2$ and $R_3$ on top of the resistor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just switch the coordinates.

`(4,0) ... (2,3);` To `(2,3) ... (4,0)`
`(2,3) ... (0,0);` To `(0,0) ... (2,3)`

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
\ctikzset{label/align=smart,bipoles/length=1.5cm}
\draw (0,0) to[R,l_=\mbox{$R_1=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (4,0);
\draw (2,3) to[R,l^=\mbox{$R_2=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (4,0);
\draw (0,0) to[R,l_=\mbox{$R_3=\SI{2}{\ohm}$},*-*] (2,3);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

I've replaced `[scale=1.25]` with `[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]`. As @Gonzalo Medina mentioned in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166334/diagonal-resistor-label-font-size-and-curved-arrows) :

> Instead of scaling the circuit, you can use x=, y=, so
>   labels, for example, won't be affected.